# How to hide a product but still access it with a link

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I've tried to create a category and set `Is Active` to no, then creating another subcategory of that category with `Is Active` set to yes, then adding the product to that category but it doesn't seem to work.
I just want to create a product that can only be accessed with a link. Anyone know how do do this?

Comment: Never mind to forgot to reindex! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a product with the visibility field set to `Catalog`, and don't assign it to any categories.
This way no one will be able to find it while browsing the catalog and it won't be visible when a search is made, but you will still be able to access it via a link.